# CRUD using MVC Architecture using PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller

I am in need to develop a site using **MVC architecture without using any frameworks.**

**Is there any CRUD example for PHP using MVC architecture so that i can able to proceed further. I search a lot. But i can't find a best example which looks cool and powerful.**

Kindly suggest me any good examples **which implements full power of MVC architecture.**

Thanks in advance...

Comment: If you think Model=Database, then that's actually the PMVC pattern. And has no bearing on how you design a CRUD interface. Also, less buzzwords please.

Comment: if you can't use a framework, you have to do it by hand. we aren't going to write your script for you.

Comment: strange question if you ask me..

Answer (score 3):

[Codeigniter From Scratch: Day 5](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-5-crud/)